# Wordpress Custom Open Graph Action

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I have a wordpress site with a custom wishlist plugin.

Now, when I an inside a post, say http://example.com/somepost, I have a button which adds the post in the user's wishlist. The action happens with the following link: http://example.com/somepost?addtowishlist

So "?addtowishlist" is the action of the wishlist plugin which gets appended in the posts url.

I created a facebook application, defined a custom action (saved) and a custom object (post).

I already read up on how to integrate open graph with a site, however my question is this:

How can I add an og action to the wishlist action? What I want is when a user adds a post to his wishlist, this action gets posted on his timeline: "User X saved LINK to his wishlist".

Can anyone point me to the right direction?